# ArcMap PostgreSQL unique sequence

Tags: arcmap, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase

I have connected my ArcMap to my PostgreSQL db using the Create Enterprise Geodatabase tool in ArcMap. I have multiple feature classes and the relevant relationships between them loaded into the db correctly.

However, I am attempting to add a unique sequence to the feature classes using the postgres sequence function as below:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_sequence;
```

I then set the default for an integer colum in my tables and assign the sequence as below:

```
SET DEFAULT nextval('my_sequence');
```

However, the sequencer works perfectly if I insert data inside PostgreSQL using a SQL statement. If I edit the same table in ArcMap I get the following error when trying to save my edits:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint
DETAIL: Key(uniq_id)=(0)already exists
```

Where am I overlooking something?

Comment: Did you enable Archiving or Versioning on that table by any chance?

Comment: I have tried this these approaches, although it lets me save the edits it still populates each new row with a sequence number of 0.

Comment: It seems that apart from the default value, there is also a unique index on the field, is that correct? I think ArcGIS doesn't like those on versioned or archived featureclasses. (because duplicate values can exist in the _H or _A tables)

Comment: Edits on versioned feature classes do not fire actions on the base table until after posting. Please [Edit] the question to contain more details on your exact procedure.

Comment: It's possible the object id that is typically used and then sequencer are both set to unique keys somehow for SDE. I would double check in pg-admin what the configurations are for the fields. Typically a sequential object is a unique key, and object id is that for Arc Desktop.